Reading configuration from Mojo annotation of class
I've written a build tool. This build tool can generate jars that conform to the requirements of Maven plugins. A Maven plugin jar contains a file called plugin.xml which contains various pieces of information about the plugin, including a list of Mojo's. My build tool generates this information by scanning all the classes in the jar for any that have the @Mojo annotation. I then use the org.ow2.asm:asm:9.7 library to extract the settings of this annotation.
The code looks like this (edited for brevity):
   public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(final String desc, final boolean visible) {
        if (MOJO_CLASSNAME.equals(desc)) {
            mojo.foundAnnotation = true;
            return new AnnotationVisitor(this.api) {
                public void visit(final String name, final Object value) {
                    if ("name".equals(name)) mojo.goal = value.toString();
                    if ("defaultPhase".equals(name)) mojo.phase = value.toString();
                    if ("instantiationStrategy".equals(name)) mojo.instantiationStrategy = value.toString();
                    if ("executionStrategy".equals(name)) mojo.executionStrategy = value.toString();
                    if ("requiresProject".equals(name)) mojo.requiresProject = (Boolean) value;
                    if ("requiresReports".equals(name)) mojo.requiresReports = (Boolean) value;
                    if ("aggregator".equals(name)) mojo.aggregator = (Boolean) value;

The visit(String name, Object value) function is supposed to pick up on all fields inside the Mojo annotation. However, it appears not to do this.
I have a Maven plugin that sets the defaultPhase to GENERATE_RESOURCES. For reasons unknown to me this field is not given to the visit() method. Which results in an incorrect value for the phase setting in the plugin.xml file.
Note that the name field inside the Mojo is read correctly. It is just the defaultPhase field that is not. I do not set any other fields explicitly. The default value for this field is 'none'.
I want to get my build tool to work. How can I fix this?
